# Listar telefones de usuários a partir de um join sem duplicar as linhas

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Boa noite,

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso fazer um join em duas tabelas, USUARIO e CONTATO.
Cada usuário possui mais de um contato (Telefone), por isso quando listo os dados ele me retorna linhas "duplicadas" com telefones diferentes pois, EX:

```
ID  | Nome      | Telefone
1   | Felipe    | 968181444
1   | Felipe    | 37056781
2   | Claudio   | 37059999
2   | Claudio   | 968899999
```

É possível eu criar uma coluna dinâmica de telefone para listar os dados desta forma  abaixo?

```
ID  | Nome      | Telefone 1    | Telefone 2
1   | Felipe    | 968181444     | 37056781
2   | Claudio   | 37059999      | 968899999
```

Pesquisei muito no google, achei algo sobre PIVOT mas não consegui desenvolver algo parecido pro que eu preciso.

Segue a query:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.NOME, c.TELEFONE
FROM USUARIO u INNER JOIN CONTATO c
ON c.USUARIO_ID = u.ID
ORDER BY u.NOME
```

Alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: Coloque na sua questão o código que já testou para tentar chegar a uma solução.

Comment: Isso não será fácil de fazer, visto que o número de telefones é dinâmico. A única forma que talvez solucione é com SQL dinâmico.

Comment: Oi, Philippe, estava verificando aqui e tem um [artigo do StackOverflow-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) que responde sua pergunta.

Comment: Tente com subquery, algo do tipo: SELECT u.usuario_id AS usu , u.nome , c.telefone AS telefone1, 
(SELECT telefone from telefone t where t.usuario_id = u.usuario_id AND t.telefone != telefone1 LIMIT 1)   AS telefone2
FROM usuario u INNER JOIN telefone c
ON c.USUARIO_ID = u.USUARIO_ID 
GROUP BY u.usuario_id
ORDER BY u.nome

Comment: Pesquise pelo operador pivot.

Comment: Consegui através da dica do graciomar. 
Coloquei uma subquerie para o telefone 2 para criar auma nova coluna.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030 ,  listagg cria uma só coluna mas concatena os valores , outra solução e , tendo algo qu identifique fazer um case com max e group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui através da dica do graciomar. Coloquei uma subquerie para o telefone 2 para criar uma coluna, com uma mudança, tive que inserir uma coluna na tabela CONTATO para saber se o telefone é 1º ou 2º. Não é a forma mais elegante mas resolve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ID as ID, u.NOME as NOME, (select 
t1.TELEFONE FROM CONTATO t1 WHERE t1.USUARIO_ID = c.ID AND t1.TELEFONE_POS = 
'1')  as TELEFONE, (select t2.TELEFONE FROM CONTATO t2 WHERE t2.USUARIO_ID = 
c.ID AND t2.TELEFONE_POS = '2') AS TELEFONE2
FROM USUARIO u INNER JOIN CONTATO c
ON c.USUARIO_ID = u.ID
ORDER BY u.NOME
```